# Why Char variable is storing past value of stack without the declaration of char array? See code?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, char, stack

I am preparing for interviews. I used to practice couple of interview questions every day. but sometimes when the things don't get me I use internet as a reference.

Now here in this case of question which says,

Q Write a program to delete middle element of stack without using data structure?
Now here I stuck at the 38th line which says

```
char x = st.pop();
```

Here how char is storing the past values, as it is not mention array how this is possible.?

```
//Java code to delete middle of a stack 
package my.project;
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
public class GFG { 
public static void main(String args[])  
 { 
     Stack<Character> st = 
               new Stack<Character>(); 

     st.push('1'); 
     st.push('2'); 
     st.push('3'); 
     st.push('4'); 
     st.push('5'); 
     st.push('6'); 
     st.push('7'); 

     deleteMid(st, st.size(), 0); 

     while (!st.empty()) 
     { 
         char p=st.pop(); 
         System.out.print(p + " "); 
     } 
 } 

 static void deleteMid(Stack<Character> st,int n, int curr) 
 { 
   if (st.empty() || curr == n) 
     return; 
   char x = st.pop(); 
   deleteMid(st, n, curr+1);   
   if (curr != n/2) 
     st.push(x); 
} 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
static void deleteMid(Stack<Character> st,int n, int curr) 
{ 
...
char x = st.pop();
```

You have a recursive method that uses a local variable. When you recursively invoke the same method again, **another** method stack is created. Space for **another** `x` is assigned.

That is a basic concept of any programming language: when you invoke a function/method, then you *reserve* some amount of memory for that specific call. Doing so forms the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) btw.

So, in other words: by recursively calling this method, you can create a "temp" storage: each method invocation will remember **its** value of `x`. So, each call to `deleteMid()` has its separate independent char `x`. Therefore the "stored" value is still in `x` when the recursive call comes back.

Answer (score 0):

your program uses a recursive call 'deleteMid()'. 
I suggest you to read recursive Tree concept. The best way to understand recursive method is to try with Fibonacci program and draw recursive tree.

you need to understand the  storage value associated with each recursive call.

```
char x = st.pop();
```

X has different value for each recursive call and when you reach your  terminating condition

```
if (st.empty() || curr == n) 
     return;
```

recursive call traverse  back and executes the statements

```
if (curr != n/2) 
     st.push(x); 
 }
```